# Laravel 6 eloquent query Model hasOne relation with $appends data

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am attempting to create a collection for a csv report that would include a Report that "hasOne" Job which has several data_list_items that will be accessible via an appends:

`protected $appends = array('datalistitems');` (in the Job model)

This query: `Report::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->with('job')->get();` returns the Report with it's Job and I can see the appends in the dump. How can I modify the query to include the Job data and the datalistitems data all in one collection?

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#572
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Report {#571
      #table: "reports"
      #dates: array:1 [
        0 => "reported_at"
      ]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [
        "id" => 2
        "description" => "Test"
        "job_id" => 1
        "user_id" => 15
        "reported_at" => "2020-07-06 17:42:00"
        "created_at" => "2020-07-06 17:43:36"
        "updated_at" => "2020-07-06 17:43:36"
      ]
      #original: array:7 [
        "id" => 2
        "description" => "Test"
        "job_id" => 1
        "user_id" => 15
        "reported_at" => "2020-07-06 17:42:00"
        "created_at" => "2020-07-06 17:43:36"
        "updated_at" => "2020-07-06 17:43:36"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [
        "job" => App\Job {#577
          #appends: array:1 [
            0 => "datalistitems"
          ]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "user_jobs"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:17 [
            "id" => 1
            "is_primary" => "no"
            "venue_id" => null
            "employment_status_id" => 33
            "venue_type_id" => null
            "user_id" => 15
            "created_at" => "2020-07-06 17:40:22"
            "updated_at" => "2020-07-06 17:40:22"
            "instrument_id" => null
            "employer_id" => 17
            "position_id" => null
            "department_id" => 22
            "work_location_id" => 1
            "project_id" => 2
            "award_id" => null
            "contract_type_id" => null
            "contract_id" => null
          ]
          #original: array:17 [
            "id" => 1
            "is_primary" => "no"
            "venue_id" => null
            "employment_status_id" => 33
            "venue_type_id" => null
            "user_id" => 15
            "created_at" => "2020-07-06 17:40:22"
            "updated_at" => "2020-07-06 17:40:22"
            "instrument_id" => null
            "employer_id" => 17
            "position_id" => null
            "department_id" => 22
            "work_location_id" => 1
            "project_id" => 2
            "award_id" => null
            "contract_type_id" => null
            "contract_id" => null
          ]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #fillable: []
          #guarded: array:1 [
            0 => "*"
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are the datalistitems populated/related to a job?

Comment: It's actually really ugly, but there the jobs table has many ids such as venue_id, employment_status_id, venue_type_id, etc. and there's a getDatalistitemsAttribute function for the appends that has a huge list of if blank_id is truthy, push it to an array and then `return DataListItem::whereIn('id', $data_list_item_ids)->get();`.

Comment: Ok, see if my answer below is sufficient then. Maybe I am not fully understanding your question here though.

Comment: The access mutator exists. What I am looking for is how to modify this query: `Report::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->with('job')->get();` to include the datalistitems.

Comment: Ok, so even though you have defined appends on your job model, it is not loading the dataitems upon serialization? Have you tried looping and manually setting append on each job?